# Unable to select image from gallery in appium android

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am using  "**java-client-5.0.4**" version, I am unable to select image from gallery.

Here is my code

```
List<AndroidElement> galleryElements = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
t.tap(galleryElements.get(0)).perform();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the resource-id

```
By selectPhoto = By.id("imageView");
driver.findElement(selectPhoto).click();
```

but here is a problem, it will always select the first image, for specific image selection you should use `xpath` with index

Comment: All images have same resource-id, that's why I use class, but it is not selecting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList and get all image list in that list. After that provide index of the arraylist you can select the any image:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> listImage=(ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("com.euradvance.classstars:id/image"));
System.out.println(listImage.size());
listImage.get(5).click();
```